# appropriate cuda version for installing pytorch using anaconda?

Tags: pytorch, anaconda

I have anaconda3 installed on my windows10 system and I want to install pytorch using anaconda.

I was looking at the official website

https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

where I see only the versions 10.2 and 11.1 for cuda are written in the selector. Now, I know I have a cuda-capable gpu in my computer, and the version is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti.

I was also checking nvidia website for finding out the compute capability of my gpu so that I can select the appropriate one in the installation. Here's the link:

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#compute

As you see, the compute capability of all the versions is at most 8.7  ( Mine was 7.5 )

Does this mean I can't use this command for installing pytorch?

conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c conda-forge

Or can I use this command? and they won't cause a problem?

Comment: You are misinterpreting the specs. Look instead at the Release Notes for the driver for your card. [The latest driver notes](https://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/471.68/471.68-win11-win10-win8-win7-release-notes.pdf) I see for your card shows it implements CUDA 11.4.

Comment: Thanks. But now that I have installed pytorch it didn't install cuda version successfully. I posted this problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68871231/cuda-version-not-installed-on-pytorch